# HTML Tidy with python

Tags: python, html, htmltidy

I am processing badly formed html pages and therefor need to do some cleaning up. http://validator.w3.org/ Tidy function produces the exact output I desired. However, I would like to clean up the HTML files as a part of a larger Python script. I tried:

```
from tidylib import tidy_document
tidy, errors = tidy_document(html)
```

but, although tidylib works fine, the output isn't exactly as "beautiful" as on the w3. I also found [library for w3c markup validation service](https://bitbucket.org/nmb10/py_w3c), but I didn't find a method for getting cleaned up HTML.
My question is: whats the best way of getting HTML's cleaned up using a Python script (may call an outside program/web solution) - the best way being output produced by w3. Should I use additional options with tidylib, is there a suitable method in the library for w3c markup validation service or should I try something else. Pointers/code snippets much appriciated.

Comment: @gnibbler -- The first reason I turned to Tidy was that BS couldn't hande the HTML:). As far as I know using HTML5lib for parsing could, yes, be and alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set tidy options through `tidylib.BASE_OPTIONS`

[PyTidy example](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html#small-example-of-use)

[Tidy options quick ref](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html)

Comment: yes, I looked at options, but I wasn't sure what options are used by w3 as a default.